# Benchmark concurrent reads for a single Google Spreadsheet via multiple App scripts

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have **one Google Spreadsheet** and I want to read that spreadsheet from multiple Google Apps Scripts (100+ scripts and 10,000+ users).

**I'm not talking about Google Apps Script Benchmarks.**

Is there a **concurrent read** limitation for a single spreadsheet via multiple Google App Scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Apps Script quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) do no mention such a limit
- Also, Apps Script quota count per project / user - not per document

**However, there is a [limit coming from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/12423768?hl=en):**

> Up to 100 people can edit and comment at the same time.

> More than 100 people can view a file, though it’s easier to publish the file and create a link.

So, if the script not only reads,b ut also edits the spreadsheet - possibly it cannot be accessed by more than 100 users simulateneously.

Also, if several users run the same script:

- Apps Script has a limit for simultaneous script executions

Comment: Actually it is related to the Google Spreadsheets API limitations. In the Documentation they have provided 500 maximum concurrent users within 100 seconds.

But the thing I need to verify is, whether it applicable for Sheet APIs in Google Apps Script as well ? 

1- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

Comment: The [Sheets API quota](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) applies just as the Apps Script quota to projects and users. `500 requests per 100 seconds per project` means 500 requests per [GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) - thereby it does not matter either 500 requests are carried out on the same file or on 500 different files. If  you use SpreadsheetApp in Apps Script it involves Sheets API in the background, so the same quota apply (additionaly to the Apps Script quota) and each call to SpreadsheetApp counts.